# How to get error object returned by wp_create_user

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

I'm creating a registration widget for my wp site and it works as expected, however if the user already exists I need a way of retrieving that information.  I'm using ajax to make the call here is my code:

```
$.post(AjaxRequest.ajaxurl, {
                    action: "send_wlm",
                    user_login: formdata[0].value,
                    user_email: formdata[1].value,
                    user_practice_role: formdata[2].value,
                    user_practice_level: formdata[3].value,
                    user_practice: formdata[4].value
                }, function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
```

PHP

```
public function wlm_user_level (){
    global $wpdb;
    $random_password = wp_generate_password( $length=12,     $include_standard_special_chars=false );
    $user_name = $_POST['user_login'];
    $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $random_password, $user_email ); }
```

My only question is, I know that it returns an error object but how do I get that object to return it from my ajax call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example code, `$user_id` will be the error object. You can test if [`is_wp_error`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_wp_error) and return the error string via `get_error_message`:

```
$user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $random_password, $user_email );
if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) )
   return $user_id->get_error_message();
```

Comment: DOH!  I actually have that implementation later on in my code:

 if (!is_object($user_id)) {...}

it's been a long day, thanks!